# Restygwt + spring mvc

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, gwt, resty-gwt

I would like to try to use RestyGWT + SpringMVC, but the internet is practically no sane information on these technologies in the bundle, please give simple examples or links to good examples. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://bitbucket.org/foal/open-logui

`org.jresearch.logui.service.LogUiController` is a SpringMVC rest controller

`org.jresearch.logui.gwt.core.client.module.logger.srv.LogUiLoggerService` is a RestyGWT that use the controller above

`/org.jresearch.logui.gwt.fragment/src/main/resources/conf/fragmentContext.xml` -  Spring MVC configuration

`org.jresearch.logui.gwt.core.client.app.LogbackUiController` - set the default service root for RestyGWT